# Ruby 1.87 vs 1.92 Date.parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby 1.87 I could do:

```
Date.parse ("3/21/2011")
```

Now in 1.9.2 I get:

> ArgumentError: invalid date

Any ideas?

Comment: @bensiu, the [docs](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/date/1.9.2/Date#parse-class_method) don't help explain the problem or provide a way to deal with it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use `strptime` and give a specific time format.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :022 > Date.strptime '03/21/2011', '%m/%d/%Y'
 => #<Date: 2011-03-21 (4911283/2,0,2299161)>
```

---

See [*michaelmichael*'s response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373165/176075) for the reason for this difference between Ruby versions.

Comment: Just curios but how would you set locale for ruby?

Comment: Looks like you can use ActiveSupport's Date extensions: http://thedevelopercorner.blogspot.com/2009/03/change-default-date-format-in-ruby-on.html

Comment: From looking at Date's `date/format.rb/_parse` method, I don't see anything checking for locale info. The code assumes a non-US format and checks for it first, followed by U.S. An out-of-range month value (13-31) triggers the problem. The best solution is to know what region the date comes from then programmatically deciding whether to use `%m/%d/%y` or `%d/%m/%y` format in `Date#strptime`.

Comment: "how would you set locale for ruby?", you don't do it specifically for Ruby. It's a system-wide setting. On Mac OS X or Linux use `man locale` at the command-line for more info. I don't remember how to set it for Windows, but it can be set.

Answer (score 26):

Per [this bug report](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/634), the ability to parse `mm/dd/yy` dates was intentionally removed in 1.9. Ruby's creator, Yukihiro Matsumoto says:

> "dd/dd/dd" format itself is very
>   culture dependent and ambiguous.  It
>   is yy/mm/dd in Japan (and other
>   countries), mm/dd/yy in USA, dd/mm/yy
>   in European countries, right?  In some
>   cases, you can tell them by accident,
>   but we should not rely on luck in
>   general cases.  I believe that is the
>   reason parsing this format is disabled
>   in 1.9.

As hansengel suggests, you can use `Date.strptime` instead.

Comment: Interesting. Then why does `Date.parse('1/1/2001')` work in Ruby 1.9.2-p180, and appear in the date.rb source code? `Date.parse('1/1/2001') #=> #<Date: 2001-01-01 (4903821/2,0,2299161)>`, `RUBY_VERSION #=> "1.9.2"` [`Date.parse`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/date/1.9.2/Date#parse-class_method)

Comment: @the Tin Man, that's parsing the first 1 as the day, and the second 1 as the month (dd/mm/yy format). You just can't tell because they're the same number ;)

Comment: @michaelmichael, thanks for finding the real reason for this. I updated my answer to reference yours, so that the accepted answer has everything correct.

Comment: @Hans Engel, Date#parse is still available, and works in all the formats, despite the linked note in the answer above. The problem is when the date value gets confused with the month. Ruby doesn't handle that well, and doesn't check the OS to automatically resolve the right format. We have to do it. The Date.parse method is not the right tool, but it remains available if needed.

Comment: @the Tin Man I didn't say `Date#parse` wasn't still available. Perhaps I'm misreading Matz's response in the above thread. What did he say was removed there, if not the ability to use `Date#parse` to parse mm/dd/yy dates?

Comment: @michaelmichael, That note is either stale, or just wrong. Date#parse is currently available in 1.9.2-p180, and parses every format, including mm/dd/yy. It still fails, as expected, when it encounters a date where the mm value is > 12, but that's as it always has been. I was looking through the source code for p180 as I wrote my comments above.

Comment: Matz could have been referring to `yy/mm/dd in Japan` but the wording is ambiguous. I haven't tested for that format, and that would be overly hard to parse for accurately when the European dd/mm/yy and US mm/dd/yy format checks occurred ahead of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have always had difficulty parsing dates with `Date.parse`.  My solution is gratutious of the [`chronic` gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/chronic).  I also like the `strptime` function found in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I like the [american_date](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date) gem for accomplishing this...

Comment: Why does this solution feel so dirty?  I tried to modify my code to use Time.strptime(...), but ran into a cascading issue with JQuery datepicker, and PostgreSQL database formats.  Hours wasted.  But the gem works perfectly...just feels hackish and dirty...expecting this issue to emerge again in the future! </rant>

Comment: @vanboom yeah, it's a little weird but the author of that gem is *the* authority on Ruby dates, so it's obviously necessary if he wrote a gem.

Answer (score 1):

```
  class << self
    def parse_with_us_format(date, *args)
      if date =~ %r{^\d+/\d+/(\d+)$}
        Date.strptime date, "%m/%d/#{$1.length == 4 || args.first == false ? '%Y' : '%y'}"
      else
        parse_without_us_format(date, *args)
      end
    end
    alias_method_chain :parse, :us_format
  end
```