# Date converion from rails 2.3 to 3.2 in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, datetime, activerecord

I am upgrading from rails 2.3 to 3.2 and I am have trouble with Date conversion.

In rails 2.3 the date conversion default format was mm/dd/yyyy and when I assigned a string in this format to a active_record model it converts the date correctly. for e.g.

I Have a user object(active_record object) and

In rails 2.3

```
user.registered_on = "10/03/2013" #=> Oct 3, 2013
```

But same thing in rails 3.2

```
user.registered_on = "10/03/2013" #=> March 10, 2013
```

How to fix this?

I have tried setting Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%m/%d/%Y' in one of the initializers file, but this does not do any good.

I have even the locales set for date, but that does not work as well.

One perfect way to reproduce this problem is:

1. Create two apps, one in rails 2.3.x version and other in rails 3.2.x version.
2. Create one model in each of the application with at-least one datetime field.
3. Create and migrate the database for both the applications.
4. Go to rails console from your terminal in each of the application.
5. Create a active_record model object and assign this "10/3/2013" string to the datetime field and see the result both are different dates.

I just need a solution, how to fix this date or datetime conversion and make it same as rails 2.3

Comment: i am on rails4 but i think that this should not change anything: `Date.parse "3/10/2013" => Thu, 03 Oct 2013` sure that there is no plugin or gem that breaks that behavior?

Comment: Have You tried this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610485/default-date-format-in-rails-need-it-to-be-ddmmyyyy#answer-8816063

Comment: I have a tztime plugin. Can this be a problem? But This plugin has been ported fom rails 2.3 app only, so according to me this should not break this behavior. Also, I Have checked the code in that plugin and I don't see any such code which can change this behavior.

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons Yes I have tried this but no help. Might need to modify something ActiveRecord TimeZoneConverion module though I am not sure.

Comment: @phoet In rails 4 this behavior is same as in rails 2.3, the problem is with rails 3.2 I guess. I have created two test apps , one in rails 3.2 and one in 4 and tested this in both.
In rails 3.2
Date.parse "10/3/2013" # => March 10, 2013
In rails 4 and in rails 2.3
Date.parse "10/3/2013" # => Oct 3, 2013

Comment: i would bet a large amount of money that the problem is not with rails 3.2

Comment: what is the value for config.i18n.default_locale in application.rb?

Comment: @awenkhh This line is commented in application.rb file and using the default config/en.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

gem "american_date" solved this problem.

https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you've upgraded your ruby version?

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7
$ ruby -r date -e "puts Date.parse('10/3/2013').month"  
10

$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p327
$ ruby -r date-e "puts Date.parse('10/3/2013').month"  
3
```

See [Ruby 1.87 vs 1.92 Date.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372464/ruby-1-87-vs-1-92-date-parse/5373165#5373165)

Comment: Yes I have upgraded the ruby version. But how do to keep this same behavior even after ruby upgrade?.